# How to get number of IDs in the current month that also appears in the previous three months in Snowflake - SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in the snowflake with a time range from for example 2019.01 to 2020.01. An ID can appear multiple times (match with) on any of the dates.

For example:
*my_table:* two columns **dddate** and **id**

| dddate | id |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-02-03 | 607 |
| 2019-01-07 | 356 |
| 2019-08-06 | 491 |
| 2019-01-01 | 607 |
| 2019-12-17 | 529 |
| 2019-04-15 | 356 |

......

Is there a way I can find the total number of IDs that appeared at least one time in the current month that also appeared at least one time in the previous three months, and group by month to show each month's number count starting from 2019-04 (The first month that has previous three months data available in the table) until 2020-01.

I am thinking of some code like this:

```
WITH PREV_THREE AS (
SELECT 
  DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', dddate) AS MONTH, 
  ID AS CURR_ID
FROM my_table mt 
INNER JOIN
(
(
SELECT 
  MONTH(DATEADD(DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', dddate), -1, GETDATE())) AS PREV_MONTH, 
  ID AS PREV_3_MON_ID
FROM my_table
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT 
  MONTH(DATEADD(DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', dddate), -2, GETDATE())) AS PREV_MONTH, 
  ID AS PREV_3_MON_ID
FROM my_table
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT 
  MONTH(DATEADD(DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', dddate), -3, GETDATE())) AS PREV_MONTH, 
  ID AS PREV_3_MON_ID
FROM my_table 
)
) AS PREV_3_MON
ON mt.CURR_ID = PREV_3_MON.PREV_3_MON_ID
)
SELECT MONTH, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS COUNTER
FROM PREV_THREE
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

However, it somehow returns an error and doesn't seem working. Could anyone please help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select distinct id
from (select t.*,
             lag(dddate) over (partition by id order by dddate) as prev_dddate
      from my_table t
     ) t
where dddate >= date_trunc('MONTH', current_date) and
      prev_dddate < date_trunc('MONTH', current_date) and
      prev_dddate >= date_trunc('MONTH', current_date) - interval '3 month';
```

You can do this for multiple months as:

```
select date_trunc('MONTH', dddate), count(distinct id)
from (select t.*,
             lag(dddate) over (partition by id order by dddate) as prev_dddate
      from my_table t
     ) t
where prev_dddate < date_trunc('MONTH', date_trunc('MONTH', dddate)) and
      prev_dddate >= date_trunc('MONTH', date_trunc('MONTH', dddate)) - interval '3 month'
group by date_trunc('MONTH', dddate);
```

Even if an `id` appears multiple times in one month, *one* of those will be first and the `lag()` will identify the most recent previous month.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I think I will still need "dddate >= date_trunc('MONTH', current_date)" condition in where clause for the multiple-month query to make sure the id appeared in the current month, am I right?

Comment: Oh, sorry the first query is only applying for the current date. The second query's record is directly the current record. Gotcha!